# How to update the response message to a slash command by API?

Tags: slack-api

**Context**

I am building a Slack app based on slash commands, which is creating an `in_channel` response message with buttons for users to interact with. The slash command is used in a private channel.

When a user clicks on a button my app is able to update that message to reflect a new status - simply by replying to the slash request with the updated message and by setting `replace_original = true`.

**Issue**

In addition I also want to update that message by a batch, e.g. when a timer has run out. I have been trying to update the message with [`chat.update`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update), but I am getting `cant_update_message` API error.

Here is the request I use for testing in Postman:

```
https://slack.com/api/chat.update?token={TOKEN}&channel={CHANNEL}&ts={TS}&text=Updated&as_user=true
```

However, according to the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update#valid_message_types) I should be able to update bot messages:

> **Valid message types**
>
> Only messages posted by the authenticated user are able to be updated
>   using this method. This includes regular chat messages, as well as
>   messages containing the `me_message` subtype. Bot users may also update
>   the messages they post.

And the message I want to update clearly belongs to my slack app and looks like a normal bot message. Here is how that message looks through [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history):

```
{
    "text": "Some text...",
    "bot_id": "Bxxxxxxxx",            
    "type": "message",
    "subtype": "bot_message",
    "ts": "{TS}"
}
```

Btw. I deleting that message using the same parameters via [`chat.delete`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete) works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to the Slack support about my question and they confirmed that its not possible to update a response message via `chat.update`.

Here is the full response:

> A `in_channel` slash command response cannot be updated by a user. Since
>   a slash command response is not using the web API and therefore not
>   associated with any particular token, it's not possible for the
>   chat.update call to determine whether it's allowed to update the
>   message or not. Hence the error.
>
> My suggestion would be to send an ephemeral slash command response or
>   a empty slash command response and then use the `chat.postMessage` API
>   method to send an "in channel" message, which can be updated later
>   using the chat.update API method.

As suggested I will now create the "in-game" message via `chat.postMessage` API method instead, which allows me to update it later. This however creates access issues for private channels. To mitigate that I will now ask the user to add my bot user to all private channel, which will give my app access to it.

I would have liked to avoid this approach in the first place, since it create an extra step for the user, but there seam to be no better alternative (btw. the github app uses the same approach).